# PHP: ImageDestroy() with imagecopy()?

Tags: php, image, memory-management, php-gd

It is possible to delete the Image-Memory for the PHP-function "imagecopyresampled()"

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12288 bytes)

For example, I have to create images in a loop:

```
<?php

  while($break===false){

    $img=imagecreate($x);

  }

  function imagecreate($x){
    $tmp= imagecreatefromjpeg($x);

    imagecopyresampled($img,$tmp,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,100);
    //imagedestroy($img); ??This would be destroying before return the $img
    return $img;
  }

?>
```

How do I use `imagedestroy()` for `imagecopyresampled()`?

Comment: `imagedestroy($tmp)`

Comment: not for imagecreatefromjpeg() for imagecopyresampled()

Answer (score 0):

Dude there is a difference between `imagedestroy()` which destroy the tmp_image from temporary folder.

`imagecopyresampled()` create a resampling image from original copy of image.